# Communicating with iframe in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building an application that allows to customize a web site. So it looks like this

```
+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
|   sidebar       |     Preview with editor                  |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| show title  [x] | iframe which shows a preview which is    |
| show logo   [ ] | also a part of application with another  |
| chage color [x] | route and allows to add and delete       |
|                 | menu items                               |
|                 |                                          |
|                 |                                          |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to say to `preview` that
we don't want to show title/show logo/change color/etc. I suppose we need to use the same controller for both `preview` and `editor`, but I don't know how to share a controller.

Is there a way to do that in Ember?

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the controller if you want to reuse it

```
App.EditorController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  showTitle:true,
  showLogo: true
  //etc
});

App.PreviewController = App.EditorController.extend({
  showTitle: false,
  //etc
});
```

Unless you are saying you need to get info from another controller, then you want to use `needs`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_needs

Comment: Yes, I tried it. The problem is that iframe runs absolutely new ember application. So I need to share data between two applications now... Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Sorry Pain Meds are making me a little dense, You'll need to manually update values between the two applications.  You can access a controller externally using `App.__container__.lookup('controller:editor')`

Comment: You could also hook up some communication using jquery's trigger and hooking up a custom event to a method in your controller, they both are fairly ugly in my opinion.  Id probably do the first, easiest to follow the code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. Get well soon, by the way. :)